# How to send POST data to a Mautic form

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, post, mautic

I am having problems when trying to send data through POST to a form registered in Mautic.

My idea is that from an ionic app I can send the data collected from a form to mautic, but it is always giving me the same error when I execute the POST from code (since postman works correctly). I am debugging the errors, I show them below:

**Errors that appear to me in the Chrome console**

POST https://mautic.mydomain.com/form/submit?formId=1 400

**Errors that appear in the mautic log**

mautic.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ BadRequestHttpException: "Invalid json message received" at /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/mautic/vendor/friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle/FOS/RestBundle/EventListener /BodyListener.php line 127 {"exception": "[object] (Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ BadRequestHttpException (code: 0): Invalid json message received at /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/mautic/vendor /friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle/FOS/RestBundle/EventListener/BodyListener.php:127) "} []

**From Postman the format of the data that is working is this:**

```
 { "mauticform": {"nombre":"Alberto", "formId": 1} }
```

**Tests that I have done:**

- I have defined the headers so that there is no CORS problem in the server
- I have also checked that the form is active and that the name of the field is "Name"
- I tried to pass the object to him without quoting the keys
- I tried to pass the values ​​without the key "mauticform"

**This is a code example thats sends the request to mautic**

```
sendToMautic(){
    const url = 'https://mautic.mydomain.com/form/submit?formId=1';

    let datos = {
      "mauticform": {"nombre":"Alberto", "formId": "1"}
    }

    this.http.post(url, datos, {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    })
    .then(data => {

      console.log('ok', data);

    })
    .catch(error => {

      console.log('Error', error);

    });

  }
```

Comment: Can you submit a [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Show your code that sending data. According to this error text ` {"exception": "[object] ` you serialization has some errors. Probably you add string to object or something like that...

Comment: I was edit my code by adding a code that sends the data to Mautic